# Veracrypt container dismounted... chances the master key still in RAM or that it can be decrypted by someone after some hours?

Tags: data-leakage, veracrypt

Suppose a Veracrypt container was mounted and dismounted later. Then CCleaner was run, Youtube was used to watch videos, websites are browsed, and so on for 3 hours. Then computer went to sleep (hibernate and pagefile disabled). What are the chances that the container can be decrypted because of whatever is left (master keys?) in the RAM or some where else??

Veracrypt version is below 1.24.

Comment: What OS is this running on? On Linux, it'll be using the kernel's dm-crypt which does wipe keys.

Comment: @forest When talking about "pagefile" it should be Windows of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally verified this but according to [Veracrypt Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/3961542951/):

> 9. When the volume is dismounted, we securely wipe the encrypted master
>    keys from memory.
> 10. When Windows is shutdown or rebooted, we securely wipe the large
>     memory region that was allocated at startup.

My interpretation is that recovering the keys after dismount would be unlikely.

Comment: Think that is only for 1.24 version... and also RAM encryption must be selected as an option in Veracrypt.

Answer (score 0):

In the current VeraCrypt version 1.25.9, I select these options in **Preferences**:

- Use Secure Desktop for password entry.
- Do not cache passwords in driver memory.
- Wipe cached passwords on exit.
- Wipe cached passwords on auto-dismount.

Enable auto-dismount volume after 30 minutes of no read/write activity.
Dismount when user logs off.

Comment: While the *password* is needed only to *open* the volume, the *master key* is needed to *access* (decrypt/encrypt) the data (you don't need the password if you have the master key). So all these *password options* don't really answer the question.